# Tool to measure packet loss for UDP protocol

Tags: udp, streaming, wireshark, packet, loss

I am trying to measure packet loss for a UDP video streaming. While streaming the video from source to destination, I run wireshark in the background to capture the traffic. But wireshark doesn't help me measure the packet loss. Is there any tool that can give the number of packets lost during UDP streaming?

Comment: What kind of packet loss do you want to measure? Packets send but not arriving at the client system, packets  send but not processed by the client application ... Also, if you use RTP for streaming and want to know the packet loss to the target system you could actually use Wireshark on the target system since it can determine the packet loss from a RTP stream since RTP contains sequence numbers. If you use your own protocol instead and have no sequence counters it is hard to find out when a packet actually got lost (or duplicated).

Comment: The packet loss I want to measure is when packets are sent but not received at the destination due to some network failure. I am not using rtp but just a udp url for video streaming.

Comment: RTP is a protocol on top of UDP which is commonly used for  streaming, VoIP.... Anyway, if you don't have any kind of sequence counter or similar in the packet you cannot find out at the destination what is missing and therefore cannot determine packet loss. Your only chance then is to count what was send at the server (maybe by capturing packets, using firewall rules with counters..), count what was received at the client and compare the number of packets.

Comment: Alright, I will look into it. Thank you very much.